# Drop down terminal that can split gnome

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, guake, yakuake

I am looking for a good drop down terminal that can be split for gnome. At work I use KDE and Yakuake and it works really good but I don't really like KDE that much. I installed Yakuake in gnome and it is really buggy so I removed it and I am looking for a good one.

I also see that there are similar topics but they are all out of date. I have looked into `terra` but the last update to the ppa was in 2013 so was avoiding that one a bit. I am already using screens so having screens nested inside tmux for multi panel terminal doesn't really sound like it will work that well.

Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome.

Comment: I am looking for something a little more updated.

Comment: hmmm, I use guake and tmux....works fine (on kde I use yakuake and tmux.) They both are quite active projects. They are also quite stable (which IMHO is a good thing for something that will be my terminal).

Comment: As the link above suggests, try using tmux or screen with Yakuake

Comment: I want to point out that this question shouldn't be marked as "duplicate" since the other question's solution was using terra and as I said, that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: The answer says terra is for older systems and suggests guake for newer (it was updated quite recently - we try to maintain posts over time, especially highly upvoted ones). There are two recent answers for 16.04 too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with `terminator` and followed [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/install-terminator-with-built-in-quake.html) guide to allow for the drop down. Not great, but it works better for my needs than the other solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I think [Tilda](https://github.com/lanoxx/tilda/) is the best dropdown terminal.

I have tried a lot of them, including Yakuake, and I have to say that Tilda is the most customizable one, at least for my taste. At the github page there is information and screenshots regarding configuration options

Tilda exists in the repositories so you can give it a try fairly easily.

Comment: Doesn't seem that tilda can have split windows.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question, I thought you meant something like having it split between gnome and kde systems.

Answer (score 1):

I used **terra** terminal for this, but unfortunately developement was abandoned a long time ago and installing manually downloaded packages doesn't work (they're installed, but the program fails to start due to some python dependencies).

I ended up using **guake** in combination with **tmux**. It's not the same since it doesn't split in two but creates a session similar to screen that you can split, but it's totally depending on keystrokes to create/split and change focus so it's not the same:

```
Ctrl + B, then % Splits vertically
Ctrl + B, then " Splits horizontally
Ctrl + B, then left/right/up/down Change focus
Ctrl + B + left/right/up/down Change focused window size
```

Again, I remember reading in some forum that somebody was requesting such a feature in guake itself, but couldn't find any actual code.